# Is there a common/standard procedure for transforming raw data into models?

Tags: machine-learning, data-visualization, data-transformation, inference, methodology

I am asking this out of curiosity, as I can't seem to find articles that describe a simple, yet standard procedure in turning raw data into models and valuable insights (i.e. visualization).

Is there actually a simple step-by-step procedure which I (assuming that I am a beginner to the field of data science) can follow, such that I can transform raw data into working models as well as visualizing them?

I understand that there are several methods out there such as clustering, gradient descent to improve the accuracy of the results, but it will be great if someone can introduce a simple method which I as a beginner, can work on and improve from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no such thing. 
First, you need education. You can get this by going to graduate school or you can take other courses. If you are gifted and determined, you may be able to get this from books by yourself.

Then you need experience. You need to model real data sets and you need to mess up (you will mess up) and learn from your mistakes.

Comment: Thank you for your response. In that case, as I am still an undergraduate, should I try out MOOCs on say Coursera and edX to enrich myself further, and also to build up on the foundations?

Comment: If you are an undergraduate you should take courses in statistics.

Comment: Alright, I'll take that into consideration. Thanks for all the advice thus far!

Comment: There isn't a standard course.  Economic models do not look like chemistry models which do not look like geology models.  Model building is domain specific.  Models in medicine are related to, but different from models in biology.  Generic "model building" is about learning the overarching principles of mathematics that are then applied in unique ways in a discipline.  Economics, for example, is a large set of inverse problems that are ultimately built on orderings and semi-orderings.  They are the strong contra case of physics models where conservation holds and the rules are different.

Comment: The last comment was meant for @Stoner.

Comment: @DaveHarris I see. Am I right to say that going along your reasoning, different areas/specializations or say, sectors in the job market require different methods to for example improve the accuracy of the statistical model being implemented? For e.g. in medical/biological data as compared to demographic data?

Comment: @Stoner sort of.  A statistician learns them all, but will likely get hired into one area.  Biometricians, econometricians, statistical physicists and the like learn their area.  It also isn't an accuracy issue.  Certain tools just don't work in some areas of research.  The problem is that there is no warning sign that something isn't working.  You just have to know that it doesn't work because statistical methods are really algorithms and an answer will always spit out from the input.  For example, a Cauchy distribution has no mean so you cannot use least squares regression with it.

Comment: @Stoner If you would use ordinary least squares regression with distributions that lack a mean, then you will still get an output, but it won't mean anything.  Indeed, you can run a regression, backtest and do all the validity checks, but it won't be until you have spent millions of dollars that you realize that everything you did was meaningless.  It can easily pass all the tests, because, as I said, it is an algorithm and there will be an output, even if spurious.  While the Cauchy distribution doesn't show up much, it does in finance, physics and biology.

Comment: @Stoner statistics and calculus are your best bets.  You should also take research methods courses to improve model validity.

Comment: @DaveHarris Thank you for your valuable insights! It certainly gave me a better grasp of where my experiences and skill sets lie as of now. :)